# Simple rspec test of initialize, include and class variable existance

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise

I am learning rspec right now and wanna test my ability class from "devise" which this code:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    @user = user || User.new
```

my current rspec looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper.rb'

describe Ability do

  let(:user) { User.new }
  let(:ability) { Ability.new(user) }

  it 'should be an instance of Abiliy' do
    # expect(@user).to be_an_instance_of User # also works
    ability.should be_an_instance_of Ability
    # passes test
  end

  it "should include CanCan::Ability" do
    expect(:ability).to include(CanCan::Ability)
    # NoMethodError: undefined method `include?'
  end

  it 'should initialize with a User' do
   pending
  end

  it 'should have @user instance variable' do
    ability.user.should == User
    # NoMethodError: undefined method `user'

  end
```

can someone offer an example. I did a research but without success....

Comment: You should use `should be_a_kind_of` when you check includes (1st NoMethodError), and `should be_instance_of` when you check instances of (2nd case)...

Comment: And for second case you also should define `attr_accessor :user` into `Ability` or define `user` method, that returns `@user`

Comment: to the second comment: Do I need `attr_accessor :user` ? or is it enough in the `initialize(user)` method? Which are there any reasons for doing that?

at the moment my test to this looks like so: `ability.instance_variable_get(:@user).should be_an_instance_of User`

Comment: No, `initialize` isn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't hurt to test CanCan like such if you are learning and playing around. However, these tests are unnecessary if you are working on a project.

The unit tests are well covered in CanCan, specifically, `spec/cancan/ability_spec.rb`. What you have done is to duplicate Ryan's work in another way :) You can also open the gem and see how it gets tested.

For using CanCan, my suggestion is to test the integrated effect in controller level, say you don't allow some role to read, then GET it and get rejected, blah blah.

Comment: I ended up with:

  `it 'should include the CanCan::Ability to work proberly' do
    ability.should be_a_kind_of(CanCan::Ability)
  end`

Comment: Jan, that's fine. You still have hard work to do to test the integrated effects :)

Answer (score 2):

First issue => `include` matcher works on any object that responds to `include?` (e.g. String or Array)

```
module M;end

class C
  include M
end

class D;end

C.new.include?(M)
NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' for #<C:0x2c5fa58>
     from (irb):10
     from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

C.include?(M)  #=>true
D.include?(M)  #=>false
C.respond_to?(:include?) #=>true
C.new.respond_to?(:include?) #=>false
```